# What does 'get yourself together' mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does 'get yourself together' mean?

> Your sister says that every week You just come home to eat and go to
>   sleep And you make plans you never keep Because your mind is always in
>   the streets You **better get yourself** together Look for something better

Song - Sreet boy by Sixto Rodriguez

Comment: same as: pull yourself together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+yourself+together), it is an idiom and means:

> 5. verb To take action to become well-organized, prepared, or in a better state of life. In this usage, a noun or pronoun can be used between **get** and **together**.
>
> You need to get yourself together and finish packing so that we can leave for the airport on time tomorrow morning.